# Farseer: Ball is not getting slower

Tags: xna, c#, physics, farseer-physics-engine

The ball is not getting slower when it rolls over a straight platform. I added friction but that changed nothing, the ball still gets not slower. I want that the ball gets slower and slower and stops rolling after a certain time. Like in real life.
How can I do that?

In addition, the ball jumps weird when it touches two platforms at the same time. Is there a possibility to avoid that weird jumping?

Jumping ball video: http://www.vidup.de/v/p2DDO/

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    World world;
    Body rectangle, rectangle2, rectangle3, rectangle4, rectangle5, ballcircle;
    Texture2D rectangleSprite, ballSprite;

    private static float _displayUnitsToSimUnitsRatio = 100f;

    public static Vector2 ToDisplayUnits(Vector2 simUnits)
    {
        return simUnits * _displayUnitsToSimUnitsRatio;
    }

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        ballSprite = Content.Load<Texture2D>("ball");
        rectangleSprite = Content.Load<Texture2D>("tile");

        if (world == null)
        {
            world = new World(new Vector2(0, 1));
        }
        else
        {
            world.Clear();
        }

        ballcircle = BodyFactory.CreateCircle(world, 0.25f, 1.0f);
        ballcircle.BodyType = BodyType.Dynamic;
        ballcircle.Position = new Vector2(2.76f, 0f);
        ballcircle.Restitution = 0.5f;
        ballcircle.Friction = 0.3f;

        rectangle = BodyFactory.CreateRectangle(world, 1.50f, 0.50f, 1.0f);
        rectangle.BodyType = BodyType.Static;
        rectangle.Position = new Vector2(2.96f, 1.16f);
        rectangle.Rotation = -0.3f;
        rectangle.Friction = 0.9f;
        rectangle.CollisionCategories = Category.Cat5;

        rectangle2 = BodyFactory.CreateRectangle(world, 1.50f, 0.50f, 1.0f);
        rectangle2.BodyType = BodyType.Static;
        rectangle2.Position = new Vector2(1.0f, 1.80f);
        rectangle2.Rotation = 1.0f;
        rectangle2.Friction = 0.9f;
        rectangle2.CollisionCategories = Category.Cat5;

        rectangle3 = BodyFactory.CreateRectangle(world, 1.50f, 0.50f, 1.0f);
        rectangle3.BodyType = BodyType.Static;
        rectangle3.Position = new Vector2(5.1f, 4.80f);
        rectangle3.Friction = 0.9f;
        rectangle3.CollisionCategories = Category.Cat5;

        rectangle4 = BodyFactory.CreateRectangle(world, 1.50f, 0.50f, 1.0f);
        rectangle4.BodyType = BodyType.Static;
        rectangle4.Position = new Vector2(3.6f, 4.80f);
        rectangle4.Friction = 0.9f;
        rectangle4.CollisionCategories = Category.Cat5;

        rectangle5 = BodyFactory.CreateRectangle(world, 1.50f, 0.50f, 1.0f);
        rectangle5.BodyType = BodyType.Static;
        rectangle5.Position = new Vector2(6.6f, 4.80f);
        rectangle5.Friction = 0.9f;
        rectangle5.CollisionCategories = Category.Cat5;
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        world.Step(Math.Min(elapsed, (1f / 60f)));
        KeyboardState kbState = Keyboard.GetState();       

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(ballSprite, ConvertUnits.ToDisplayUnits(ballcircle.Position),
                                       null,
                                       Color.White, ballcircle.Rotation, new Vector2(ballSprite.Width / 2.0f, ballSprite.Height / 2.0f), 1.0f,
                                       SpriteEffects.None, 0f);

        spriteBatch.Draw(rectangleSprite, ConvertUnits.ToDisplayUnits(rectangle.Position),
                                        null,
                                        Color.White, rectangle.Rotation, new Vector2(rectangleSprite.Width / 2.0f, rectangleSprite.Height / 2.0f), 1f,
                                        SpriteEffects.None, 0f);

        spriteBatch.Draw(rectangleSprite, ConvertUnits.ToDisplayUnits(rectangle2.Position),
                                        null,
                                        Color.White, rectangle2.Rotation, new Vector2(rectangleSprite.Width / 2.0f, rectangleSprite.Height / 2.0f), 1f,
                                        SpriteEffects.None, 0f);

        spriteBatch.Draw(rectangleSprite, ConvertUnits.ToDisplayUnits(rectangle3.Position),
                                        null,
                                        Color.White, rectangle3.Rotation, new Vector2(rectangleSprite.Width / 2.0f, rectangleSprite.Height / 2.0f), 1f,
                                        SpriteEffects.None, 0f);

        spriteBatch.Draw(rectangleSprite, ConvertUnits.ToDisplayUnits(rectangle4.Position),
                                        null,
                                        Color.White, rectangle4.Rotation, new Vector2(rectangleSprite.Width / 2.0f, rectangleSprite.Height / 2.0f), 1f,
                                        SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
        spriteBatch.Draw(rectangleSprite, ConvertUnits.ToDisplayUnits(rectangle5.Position),
                                       null,
                                       Color.White, rectangle5.Rotation, new Vector2(rectangleSprite.Width / 2.0f, rectangleSprite.Height / 2.0f), 1f,
                                       SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In addition, the ball jumps weird when it touches two platforms at the
>   same time. Is there a possibility to avoid that weird jumping?

Nope your going to get that behavior with 2 platforms. You should combine them together into 1 shape. If the shape is more complex you can create a polygon that encompasses the entire area.

Anyways friction is going to take a very very long time to stop a perfectly round object. However, you can apply `angularDamping` to the object which will continually apply force with the goal of making the object stable.

A really good resource is the [Box2D Manual](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html) and [iforce2d](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/).

Comment: Thanx. It works.